# Unterschied zwischen 'Komplementarität', 'Synergie(-effekten)' und 'Symbiose'?

Tags: difference

Gibt es, im bildungssprachlichen Kontext, einen Unterschied zwischen den Wörtern "Synergie(-effekte)" und "Symbiose(-effekte)" bzw. zu "Komplementarität"?

Ich verstehe, dass es einen Unterschied zwischen Komplementarität und den anderen beiden Begriffen gibt, wenn man das Wort allein betrachtet.

Wenn ich jedoch beschreiben möchte, dass zwei Kräfte (ggf. gegensätzlicher Natur) **miteinander wirken/arbeiten zur Erreichung eines gemeinsamen Ziels (wechselseitige Ergänzung)**, worin liegt dann der Unterschied? Kann man das bspw. aufgreifen als "Komplementarität nutzen"? Wo wäre dann der Unterschied zu den Synergieeffekten der beiden Kräfte gemeinsam? Ich verstehe alle Begriffe als eine Art gegenseitige Unterstützung/Wechselwirkung.

Mit Kräfte sollen nicht physikalische Kräfte gemeint sein, sondern im weiteren Sinne.

Comment: Zwei Dinge, die zueinander *komplementär* sind, sind (nur) komplette Gegensätze -  sie *können* sich zu einem größeren Ganzen zusammenfügen, *müssen* aber nicht. Es ist unklar, was das mit Symbiose oder Synergie zu tun hat.

Comment: Ich dachte "komplementär" meint das jeweils andere ergänzend. Ich habe versucht, klarzustellen, dass ich in allen drei Begriffen diese "wechselseitige Ergänzung" finde und mich der Unterschied darin interessiert. @tofro

Comment: Ich würde in diesem Zusammenhang nur "Synergie" verwenden. Ich stimme zu, daß "komplementär" nur "einander entgegengesetzt" bedeutet und nicht unbedingt "das jeweils andere ergänzend". Symbiose würde ich nur im Zusammenhang mit Biologie/Organismen verwenden.

Comment: Das sind drei vielleicht ähnliche, aber doch verschiedene Begriffe, die auch üblicherweise in verschiedenen Kontexten benutzt werden. Die Frage nach dem Unterschied ergibt von daher für mich keinen rechten Sinn.

Comment: Komplementär heißt nicht unbedingt 'entgegengesetzt'. Aber zwei Dinge sind komplementär, wenn auf ein Ding etwas zu trifft, und auf das andere nicht - sie zusammen aber die Gesamtheit der möglichen Zustände von 'etwas' abdecken. Die Menge der Blauäugigen ist komplementär zur Menge der Menschen mit anderen Augenfarben - aber entgegengesetzt ist es nicht, ergänzend auch nicht. Aber zusammen bilden sie die Menge aller Menschen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die spärlich fließenden Antworten zeigen meiner Meinung nach, dass deine Vermutung, die Begriffe seien so ähnlich, dass es sich lohne, Unterschiede herauszuarbeiten, nicht geteilt wird.

Meine kurze Zusammenfassung:

- *Komplementarität* heißt, es gibt wenig oder gar keine Überlappung. Das ist völlig wertfrei, es beinhaltet nicht, dass die beiden verglichenen Objekte zusammen gelegt werden (sollen) oder gar ein gemeinsames Ziel verfolgen.
- *Synergien* ergeben sich ganz im Gegenteil, wenn es viel Überlappung gibt, also bei der Zusammenlegung zweier Firmen beispielsweise eine Einkaufsabteilung überflüssig wird oder sich einem neuen Themenfeld widmen kann. Hier gibt es ein gemeinsames Ziel, den Gewinn des gesamten Konzerns.
- Eine andere Art von *Synergie* gibt es, wenn das  Zwischenprodukt des einen vom anderen (mit-)genutzt werden kann. Auch hier ist nur von gespartem Aufwand die Rede, die Ziele können trotzdem unterschiedlich sein. Ähnlich kann man bei nur einer Partei aber zwei Zielen argumentieren: Schneeräumen ist vorgeschrieben und bietet gleichzeitig sportliche Betätigung.
- *Symbiose* kenne ich nur aus der Biologie, es heißt nur, dass jede Partei einen Nutzen hat. Schon die Übertragung auf die menschliche Gesellschaft (z. B. Studentin kann umsonst wohnen, kümmert sich aber um Besorgungen/den Garten) würde man damit eher nicht bezeichnen. Typisches Neusprech für diesen Sachverhalt ist *Win-win-Situation* oder aus der Spieltheorie der Begriff *Nichtnullsummenspiel*.